# If we delete paused GTM tags, will it improve the website performance ? Will it reduce the unused JS?

Tags: google-tag-manager, gtmetrix

I am trying to improve the performance of my website ... but i am not sure if i delete the paused GTM tags will it help me in any way or not ? If yes then how it will help, like by reducing the size of unused js ?

Answer (score 1):

Paused tags aren't included in the library. Deleting paused tags will achieve nothing.

It is expected that GTM would have unused code reported by lighhouse. To reduce it, you can go and delete unused active triggers and tags, especially when deleting then would lead to removing the whole class or type of triggers.

So again, less unique types of triggers and tags you use - less unused JS in lighthouse report. But that is pretty much a vanity metric when it comes to tag management systems.

Comment: thanks for your response, so if we delete the triggers, tags and variables which are not in use will help in reducing the GTM script size right ? but deleting paused tag will not help.
Thanks again!!!

Comment: yes, but deleting unused active tags will help with unused code only when deletion implies getting rid of the whole type. So only if you delete the last tag/trigger of this type. For example, the last Visibility trigger or the last Timer trigger. That automatically removes the trigger's sort of class from the library, hence less unused code. But again, it's not worth it to be bothered by it. It's not like that unused code really influences anything. The library is pretty small and it gets cached too.

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't any bad code like weird JS that is somehow slow down your website. The help will be very little

Here is a quick way about testing if GTM is affecting the performance.

---

1. Open the Chrome devtool when browsing the website
2. Search `gtm-` in the network tab

[image]

3. Right click the GTM-xxxxx request , choose `block request URL`

[image]

Then compare the *Dom Ready* and *Window Loaded* Timing is different or not

[image]

=>

If yes, please find someone who knows about JS and help you to debug what is wrong within the GTM. Most of the case GTM would not cause issue on performance

If not, then need to find what is other reason that is slowing down the performance. Most of the time, it is the source code issue or server respond slowly. There will be a lot of potential reason and need to check one by one.

Maybe the `Lighthouse` in the Chrome Devtool will help you find more information.